# Paypal custom data - safety issue

Tags: paypal

I've got paypal recurring payment buttons on my website.

I'm passing subscription type and user id through custom data.

It's reversed and base64 coded. But still someone can edit it and change subscription type or/and user id. Am I right?

Should i check payment amount and then verify type or what...

Is custom data field in paypal button safe to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encrypt your payment buttons - see [Securing Your PayPal Payments Standard Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/).